# Coding do-while loop?

Tags: java

I am working on this assignment for my AP Comp Sci class in which I need to write a program (using Eclipse) that asks the user for the number of items they bought and I need to create the code with a do-while loop. Each time through the loop has to pertain to a different item. For each of these items, the user needs to enter the cost. Then, I need to print the total cost of all of the items and the total after a 9% sales tax and print the result.

I tried to do it, but I can't get the total to print out correctly and it doesn't work if I take out the for-loop. Can you give me some pointers on how to fix it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("You went shopping on Cyber Monday.");

    do {
        System.out.println("How many items did you purchase?");
        int num = kbReader.nextInt();
        for(int x = 0; x < num;) {
            System.out.println("What did you purchase?");
            String item = kbReader.next();
            System.out.println("How much did it cost?");
            double cost = kbReader.nextDouble();
            break;
        }
        break;
    } while(true);

    double total = cost;
    double totalTax = total + (total * 0.09);
    System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
    System.out.println("Total after tax: $" + totalTax);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 0):

**Your Implementation**

There are three errors in your code:

1. `x++` in the for loop is missing
2. You should declare `cost` ouside the `do-while` loop and you should sum (`cost += kbReader.nextDouble();`) single items costs in the `for` loop.
3. You should not break the `for` loop (when `x` reaches the target number it breaks automatically).

Moreover don't forget to close your scanner after the `do-while`: `kbReader.close();`

This code should works:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("You went shopping on Cyber Monday.");
         double cost = 0;
         do
         {
         System.out.println("How many items did you purchase?");
         int num = kbReader.nextInt();
         for(int x = 0; x < num;x++)
         {
             System.out.println("What did you purchase?");
             String item = kbReader.next();
             System.out.println("How much did it cost?");
             cost += kbReader.nextDouble();
         }
         break;
         }while(true);
         kbReader.close();
         double total = cost;
         double totalTax = total + (total * 0.09);
         System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
         System.out.println("Total after tax: $" + totalTax);
     }
```

**Correct do-while implementation**

I would like to suggest you another implementation because I think that if you use a `do-while` you shouldn't use also the `for` loop.
This is the code:

```
Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("You went shopping on Cyber Monday.");
double cost = 0;
int x = 0;
System.out.println("How many items did you purchase?");
int num = kbReader.nextInt();
do
{
  System.out.println("What did you purchase?");
  String item = kbReader.next();
  System.out.println("How much did it cost?");
  cost += kbReader.nextDouble();
  x++;
} while(x<num);
kbReader.close();
double total = cost;
double totalTax = total + (total * 0.09);
System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
System.out.println("Total after tax: $" + totalTax);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code. The first one, is that it will break out of the two loops after they are being run only once.

`while (true)` is generally not a good idea. I suggest that you ask how many items above the do while loop, and set a counter to 0. Increment the counter by one inside the while loop body, and then test it in the while statement as such:

```
int count = 0;
do {
   <code body>
   count++;
} while (count < num);
```

Further, you are trying to access a total variable that lives inside the while loop scope while outside. It will not allow you to compile. Initialize it above the while loop, and increment it (e.g. `total += cost;`) while inside the loop. You can get rid of the for loop altogether.

Give that a try!